# retrieving nested data from ajax xml

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml

My ajax function below finds and returns xml data to the `one` variable as `<name>johnny>/name>`
I cannot get my `two` variable to display anything. Shouldn’t it display “johnny”.  Johnny also has a value of 2, essentially I want to retrieve that 2 value.

```
function xmlParser(xml) {


            $(xml).find(“user”).each(function () {


            var one = $(this).find("name");
            var two = $(one).find(“johnny").text();

        console.log(two);


  })


}
```

example xml:

```
 <names>
      <name>
      <value>16</value>
      <gname>Johnny</gname>
      <type>String</type>
       </name>
    <name>
      <value>12</value>
      <gname>Sarah</gname>
      <type>String</type>
    </name>
  </names>
```

Comment: What about `$(this).find("name").text()` Since it seems like `name` node does not have any node with the name `johnny`

Comment: OT: Don't use "smart" quotes in Javascript.

Comment: adding .text(); still renders nothing to the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
       $(xml).find("user").each(function () {
         $(this).find('name').each(function() {
               var name = $(this).find("gname").text();
               console.log(name); //gets all your names

          });
      });
```

Comment: that works great for getting the names, thanks, still can't seem to get any data below the gname like value though, but ill figure it out. Thanks Ani.